# Collection select items on aggregate unique values

Tags: php, laravel

is there a way to select from a collection items on unique values?
For example:

```
    {
        "identifier": 1,
        "name": "Robert",
        "lastname": "Brown",
        "age": "30"
    },
    {
        "identifier": 2,
        "name": "Robert",
        "lastname": "Brown",
        "age": "30"
    }
```

In this collection I would like to get only one of the two items because they have same name,lastname and age.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Treat it as a normal array, write some code and if you have problems please post your attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nice method available in laravel

```
  $unique = $collection->unique('name');

  $unique->values()->all();
```

[official laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-unique)